# Cannot access first() element from an empty list when using Grails SortedSet

Tags: java, grails

I am working on creating some grails domain objects dynamically and then adding them a SortedSet declared in another grails domain object. I have created a Project class, filled in its values, and checked to make sure it is valid. It is valid, so I want to add this Project to an Employee.

My code essentially goes like this

```
Employee employee = Employee.get(session.empid)
...
//populate some Project objects
...
//add projects to employee
employee.addToProjects(project)
```

What could be going wrong here? If I do a project.validate(), and then check for errors, the only one says that project has no valid employee associated with it - but that should go away once I do the employee.addToProjects. Employee hasMany Project objects, and it is declared like so:

```
class Employee implements Comparable
{
    static hasMany = [projects:Project]

    static constraints = 
    {
    }

    static mapping = {
        projects cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
    }

    SortedSet<Project> projects = new TreeSet<Project>();
}


public class Project implements Comparable
{  
    static belongsTo = [employee:Employee]

    static hasMany = [roles:Role]

    static mapping = {
          roles lazy:false, cascade:"all,delete-orphan"
    }

    @XmlElement
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();


    /*
     * return sorted list.  overwriting default getter was causing error upon saving multiple roles.
     *
     */
    def List getSortedRoles(){
        Collections.sort(roles, new RoleComparator());
        return roles;
    }


    String toString()
    {
        return name
    }


    // compare by latest date of roles, then by name + id
    //if this is too intrusive, implement comparator with this logic and sort on rendering page
       int compareTo(obj) {
           if(obj == null){
               return 1;
           }

           def myMaxRole = findMaxRole(roles);
           def rhsMaxRole = findMaxRole(obj.roles);

           def rcomparator = new RoleComparator();

           System.out.println(myMaxRole.title + " " + rhsMaxRole.title + " " + rcomparator.compare(myMaxRole, rhsMaxRole));
           return rcomparator.compare(myMaxRole, rhsMaxRole);
       }

    def List getExpandableRoleList()
    {
        return LazyList.decorate(roles, FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Role.class));
    }


    def setExpandableRoleList(List l)
    {
        return roles = l;
    }

        def Role findMaxRole(roles){
            RoleComparator rc = new RoleComparator();

            Role maxRole = roles.first();
            for(role in roles){
                if(rc.compare(maxRole, role) > 0){
                    maxRole = role;
                }
            }

            return maxRole;
        }

public class Role implements Comparable
{

    static belongsTo = [project:Project]
    static hasMany = [roleSkills:RoleSkill,roleTools:RoleTool]

    static mapping = {
        duties type:"text"
        roleSkills cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
        roleTools cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false

    }

    static contraints = {
        endDate(nullable: true)
    }

    boolean _deleted
    static transients = ['_deleted']

    @XmlElement
    String title = ""
    @XmlElement
    String duties = ""
    @XmlElement
    int levelOfEffort
    @XmlElement
    Date startDate = new Date()
    @XmlElement
    Date endDate = new Date()
    @XmlElement
    Date lastModified = new Date()
    @XmlElement
    LocationType locationType = new LocationType(type: "Unknown")
    @XmlElement
    String rank
    @XmlElement
    List<RoleSkill> roleSkills = new ArrayList<RoleSkill>()
    @XmlElement
    List<RoleTool> roleTools  = new ArrayList<RoleTool>()

    String toString()
    {   
        return title;
    }

    int compareTo(obj) {

        return title.compareTo(obj.title)
    }

    def skills() {
        return roleSkills.collect{it.skill}
    }
    def tools() {
        return roleTools.collect{it.tool}
    }
}
```

Comment: what do the domain objects look like? Do your project object implement Comparable?

Comment: added the relevant info - and yes, they implement comparable

Comment: Also - I will just point out again, when I make the Project object, it returns everything valid except for no value for employee, but this should be added when I add the project to the Set in Employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

went back to basics and wrote an integration test using your objects and it all works fine, you error must be in how you are saving the objects

test snippet

```
void testSomething() {
    def emp = new Employee(first:"Aaron", last:"Saunders")
    emp.save()

    emp =  Employee.get(1)

    emp.addToProjects(new Project(name:"Project 3"))
    emp.addToProjects(new Project(name:"Project 1"))
    emp.addToProjects(new Project(name:"Project 2"))

    emp.save()

    println Employee.get(1)

    println Employee.get(1).projects.first()
}
```

my objects..

```
public class Project implements Comparable
{  
    static belongsTo = [employee:Employee]

    String name;

    static mapping = {
          roles lazy:false, cascade:"all,delete-orphan"
    }


    String toString()
    {
        return name
    }


    // compare by latest date of roles, then by name + id
    //if this is too intrusive, implement comparator with this logic and sort on rendering page
       int compareTo(obj) {
           if(obj == null){
               return 1;
           }


           return this.name.compareTo(obj.name);
       }

}

class Employee implements Comparable
{
    static hasMany = [projects:Project]

    String first, last
    static constraints = 
    {
    }

    static mapping = {
        projects cascade:"all,delete-orphan", lazy:false
    }

    SortedSet<Project> projects = new TreeSet<Project>();

    int compareTo(obj) {
        if(obj == null){
            return 1;
        }
           return this.name.compareTo(obj.name);
    }

}
```

Comment: I will do a comparison of this and mine. I didn't post the creation of the Project objects, because there is more involved than what I posted, and I have to make several child objects to create a project

Answer (score 17):

Having [].first() throw a 'java.util.NoSuchElementException: Cannot access first() element' from an empty List  seems 'un-groovy' in my opinion.

I use groovy's safe-deference operator (?)  to avoid NPEs/NoSuchElementException

```
def list=[]
println list[0] //returns null
println list.first()    //NoSuchElementException
println list?.first()  //NoSuchElementException.  Would prefer it to return null.
def list2=[null,3,6]
println list2.first()  // returns null
println list2[0]       //returns null
```

It seems frustrating that .first() is the only groovy list method to throw an exception.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Documentation should be changed to clarify this.
list[0] - returns null if element not found. doesn't distinguish between empty list and case when first element happens to be null.

.first() returns the first element only if there is a first element, otherwise throws NoSuchElementException

Comment: Amen! Why throw an exception for the absolutely non-exceptional event of a list being empty.

Comment: I also would prefer to get a `null` for `[].first()` or at least let `[]?.first()` return `null`... otherwise I have to check like `def tt = [].size()>0?[].first():null`

Comment: The problem is []?.first() works, but conditionally tests if the list is null, not if the first element is null. If you're hoping for first() to return null when the list is empty, the trouble is, this is ambiguous whether the list is empty or whether the first element is null. Of course you can do this:  [].isEmpty() ? null : [].first(), which says explicitely what you want.

Comment: I would profer the argument that if you restructure your code, you'll probably end up with better code if you test isEmpty() on the list as your way of dealing with the possibility of an empty list, rather than ignoring the possibility, or hoping ?. at some point with dealing with it. Then again, it's subjective and a matter of style, groovy tends to like to ignore problems.

Answer (score 0):

first() is part of groovy. calling first on an empty set will throw a no such element exception.

add the project to the employee and then try saving the employee.

try saving using code like:

```
if(!employee.save()) 
    employee.errors.allErrors.each {
        println it
    }
```

try removing the line : SortedSet projects = new TreeSet();

Comment: As far as I can tell, the exception happens on the line employee.addToProjects(proj) and it never makes it to the save() function.

Comment: also, when I took out the SortedSet line my table got fubar'd or something, and I had to re-create employee, because I got a DIFFERENT message about first() returning null on trying to load an employee